# Google Analytics visits counter decreasing

Tags: google-analytics

A week ago my page had 1500 visits, now the counter shows 1000. I have another website using Google Analytics and the counter for that one also decreased from 500 visits this month to 400.

Is there a cause for this or is it that Google Analytics is not a good service? Is there other free web statistics service I could use?

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the same time frames? are you sure there's no filters or segments in place the 2nd time around?

Comment: All visits up to this date

Comment: It seems this question was locked because talking against google is not allowed (which I actually haven't). However, I will do further research, instead of editing my question. Thank you. And yes, it is a technical question as **the cause for the error could be a misconfiguration**.

Comment: GA questions often get closed here, or moved to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ since there's a big gray line between coding vs. reporting when it comes to a GA question.  And it doesn't help when a lot of mods here don't know GA and just blanket close any of them, even when it's blatantly a coding issue :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I had that same problem too with Google. Web statistics are meant to be reliable, otherwise, what's the point in having them?

A counter that freezes or decreases visits number defeats the purpose of having statistics at all and it's a sign of a bad service.

Not all is lost, here is a list of other web statistics services: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/google-analytics-alternatives/

most of them offer a free trial or service, but it would be interesting to know which free service it is know for its reliability, not the huge amount of features they offer most users wont find useful.